# Dynamically adding menu item in actionbar

Tags: android

I am creating a android project which has three activity.I include this three activity in `MainActivity` using `TabHost`.The problem is if i want to add different menu item for these activities how can i do this.and how to add menus dynamically for separate activity.
Is there any way to get the activity name and add menu for that activity dynamically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301113/dynamically-add-action-item-in-action-bar  try this link it will help you

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the issue you're facing? What are you seeing in your ActionBar menu? The default behaviour is to populate the menu from the activity that currently has the user focus.